# Format of a table

Tags: html, html-table

I have trouble formatting my table data. The picture explains my problem. I have tried to use the foreach and then add a new  in the foreach. but then i takes all for all of my documents i have in my entire database, when i only want the the ones for that id.

[image]

This is my code of the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="font-size:100%!important" id="prover">
        <tr style="cursor:default!important;">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Navn</th>
            <th>CPR</th>
            <th>Dokumenter</th>                
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    <?php while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($results)):
            $docs = dbHelper::getTestDoc( $row[id] );?>

        <tr style="cursor:default!important;">
            <td><?php echo utf8_encode($row['id']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo utf8_encode($row['navn']); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['cprnr'] ?></td>

            <?php  while ($docrow = mssql_fetch_array($docs)){ ?>


            <td><?php  echo '<span>';


                             for ($i = 0; $i < count($docrow['docID']); ++$i) 
                             {
                                 if($i == 1 || 2)                                         
                    if ($docrow['Approved'] == 1){
                        echo '<span class="btn btn-success btn-xs pull-left" id="'.$docrow['docID'].'" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Godkend dokument"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></span>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    }else{
                        echo '<span class="btn btn-warning btn-xs pull-left aprove-doc" id="'.$docrow['docID'].'" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Godkend dokument"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                                                    echo '<span class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-left denied-doc" id="'.$docrow['docID'].'" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Afvis dokument"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></span>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

                    }
                echo    '<a href="../blabla.php?did='.$docrow['docID'].'">'.utf8_encode($docrow['displayName']). '</a> ';

                                            if ($docrow['DocType'] == 1){
                                                echo '(Afs. praktik)';
                                            }else if ($docrow['DocType']==2){
                                                echo '(Vdr. skema)';                        
                                            }else 
                                                echo '';                                            

                        echo '<span class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right delete-doc" id="'.$docrow['docID'].'" title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Slet"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                    </span><br/>';

                            }    


            }  ?>

            </td>

            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[id] ?>"  <?php //echo $row['selected'] ?> ></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the number of columns don't match – could this be due to your `while` loop?

Basically, for correct HTML table formatting correctly, every row and header row (the `<th>` part) must either have the same number of columns/`<td>`s or the `colspan` attribute to span over multiple columns.

Do you have the total number of possible columns before you output the data? Then you could use this as colspan value in the last `<th>` and in a 'foreach' loop on the other rows, inserting empty cells where no data is present.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem, I just checked and i got 5 x <th> and 5 x <td>.
There is nothing wrong with the code as it stands, I just dont know how I can make the line break in table if there is more than 1 document.

Comment: Ahh, in this case you mustn't use `<span>`, because that's an inline element. Try putting the documents in `<p>` or `<div>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<?php  while ($docrow = mssql_fetch_array($docs)){ ?>
            <td>`
```

use

```
<?php  while ($docrow = mssql_fetch_array($docs)){ ?>
            <div>
```